# Batch - how to read from file with path

Tags: backup, batch, robocopy

I would like to do a robocopy of files whose path is listed in .txt (below is the file structure):

```
Path
C:\file1
C:\file2
etc.
```

I need to do a robocopy and save the name of the file. How can I do this? I've tried with for loop but it failed - see my example below:

```
for /f %%f in (test.txt) do robocopy /mir %%f D:\temp2
```

Comment: "*I've tried with for loop but it failed.*" Great! Now, please share your script, so others can help you fix/improve it.

Comment: Example 'for /f %%f in (test.txt) do robocopy /mir %%f D:\temp2'

Comment: to copy a specific file from a specific folder, you would use `robocopy /mir sourcefolder destinationfolder filename` which can include multiple filenames. your example fails because there is no such folder named "c:\file1" since it is a *file*. But assuming all the files are in a single path, you might try `robocopy /mir c:\sourcedir d:\temp2 "%%f"` probably a good idea to use quotes for files that have spaces in their names.